# Scrollbars showing with AdWhirl ads?

Tags: android, adwhirl

There's horizontal scrollbar for AdWhirl ads on my Nexus S 2.3.2 
Admob ads are OK. 
I gave all width to AdWhirl but ads are too long. 
Is there solution to set preferable ad size? I tried to change AdWhirl 
layout size but I received the same ads and just had vertical and 
horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste your XML code and I'll see if I can spot the problem?

Comment: Xml part is just a single element: 

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/question_layout_ad"
            android:padding="0dp" android:layout_margin="0dp"/>  



and Java code is simple too: 

            AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(refresh);
            AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(isTest);
            adWhirlView = new AdWhirlLayout(activity, activity.getString(R.string.ad_whirl_id));
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(parentView);
            layout.addView(adView);

Comment: I can think it may be is that by default your LinearLayout orientation is set to horizontal. Just set it to Vertical and it usually does the trick for problems like these.

If that doesn't work, do you know what AdWhirl are sending you? Is it a scrollview? An image? If you are able to access that the problem may be in there.

Comment: 1. All my activies are marked as android:screenOrientation="portrait" and application doesn't support "landscape". 2. No, I don't know and I couldn't find any customizations. For example I can tell AdMob what ad size I want to show: public class AdSize  {
    public static final com.google.ads.AdSize BANNER;
    public static final com.google.ads.AdSize IAB_MRECT;
    public static final com.google.ads.AdSize IAB_BANNER;
    public static final com.google.ads.AdSize IAB_LEADERBOARD; but there's nothing relative in AdWhirl.

Comment: Your activity orientation may be portrait, but your linearlayout orientation can still be horizontal, meaning it can run off the side of the screen.

Comment: How can I check it and set it to portrait? I tried to set fixed size of my layout but I received the same banners.

Comment: Just put it in the XML: <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

Comment: @NotACleverMan.. buddy i have set Adhwirl in my app...but it is showing only one ad on the screen...
i have searched alot but coudnt find any solution for it.
can u please help pe??